# Using gui.createMacBuiltin makes windows app now work in node webkit

Tags: webkit, node-webkit

Just started trying to create a menubar for my node webkit app, and I followed the instructions straight from the master Roger Wang himself...here:

https://github.com/rogerwang/node-webkit/wiki/Window-menu

Here is the code:

```
var gui = require('nw.gui');
var mb = new gui.Menu({type:"menubar"});
mb.createMacBuiltin("your-app-name");
gui.Window.get().menu = mb;
```

Works beautifully on mac, but makes the PC app not work. Any ideas now to solve it?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I expect that `createMacBuiltin` isn't defined when you're running on non-Mac platforms.  You should probably protect that code with an os-specific check, like this:

```
var gui = require('nw.gui');
var mb = new gui.Menu({type:"menubar"});
if (process.platform === "darwin") {  // this should indicate you're on Mac OSX
    mb.createMacBuiltin("your-app-name");
}
gui.Window.get().menu = mb;
```

This is assuming, of course, that the surrounding code is platform independent and you want it to run on all platforms.

Comment: Presumably you could also use feature detection and instead of checking for the platform you could check if the method exists.